# Handling Perforce message in Perl when there are no new files submitted

Tags: perl, exception, perforce

I am trying to code a Perl subroutine that returns an array of files that has been modified and submitted to the Perforce repository from `$previous_date` until `now`. This is how the subroutine looks like:

```
sub p4_files {
    my ($previous_date) = @_;

    my $files = "//depot/project/design/...rtl.sv"
    my $p4cmd = "p4 files -e $files\@$previous_date,\@now";

    my @filelist = `$p4cmd`;
    chomp @filelist;

    return @filelist;
}
```

The subroutine works as expected if there are files submitted between the given dates. However, it happens that no new changes are made, and executing the `p4 files` command returns a message instead:

```
prompt% p4 files -e //depot/project/design/...rtl.sv\@25/05/2017,\@now
prompt% //depot/project/design/...rtl.sv\@25/05/2017,\@now - no revision(s) after that date.
```

How should I handle this in my Perl script? I would like to exit the script when such a situation is encountered.

Comment: What's in `@filelist` if there are no changes? Try running the command with `2>/dev/null` to hide the message.

Comment: Hm, good question. Nothing actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do nothing if the array isn't populated.

```
my @filelist = `$p4cmd`;
good_bye() unless @filelist;  # Say goodbye and exit.

chomp @filelist;
```

To suppress the message, just redirect stderr of the command to a bitbucket:

```
my $p4cmd = "p4 files -e $files\@$previous_date,\@now 2> /dev/null";
```

Comment: If you redirect stderr, the check no longer works because now @filelist contains the error message...

Comment: @SamStafford: If you redirect stderr to /dev/null, it gets redirected to stdout?

Comment: whoops, missed that it was going to /dev/null instead of to stdout.  :)  Though that does still leave the drawback of it not working cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `p4` returns exit code 0 regardless of whether it finds some files or whether it returns the "no revision(s) after that date" message. That means you have to parse the output.

The simplest solution is probably to exit the script `if $filelist[0] =~ / - no revision\(s\) after that date\./`. The downside is we don't know how "stable" that message is. Will future versions of Perforce emit this message exactly, or is it possible they would reword?

Another option is to use the `-s` switch: `my $p4cmd = "p4 -s files -e $files\@$previous_date,\@now";`. That causes `p4` to prepend the "severity" before every line of output. If a file is found, the line will start with `info:`, while the "no revision(s) after that date" will start with `error:`. That looks a bit more stable to me: exit `if grep /^error:/, @filelist`. Watch out for the last line; when you use the `-s` switch, you get an extra line with the exit code.

Yet another option would be to use P4Perl. In that case you'd get the results as structured data, which will obviate the parsing. That's arguably the most elegant, but you'd need the P4Perl module first.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `-F` flag to tame the output:

```
my $p4cmd = "p4 -F %depotFile% files -e $files\@$previous_date,\@now";
```

and then go ahead with the:

```
my @filelist = `$p4cmd`;
good_bye() unless @filelist;  # Say goodbye and exit.
```

`@filelist` will be empty if there are no lines of output containing a `%depotFile%` field, and now your caller doesn't need to try to parse the depot path out of the standard `p4 files` output.

If you want to massage the `p4 files` output further, take a look at `p4 -e files (args)` so you can see what the different fields are that you can plug into `-F`.

Comment: Perforce says -F is an invalid option

Comment: Update your p4 executable (client updates are free).